# Can some one explain why WordPress pagination doesn't like custom loops?

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination, wordpress-theming

I have the exact same issue as [This other stack post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14286352/pagination-elements-not-displaying-in-wordpress-loop). How ever I cannot figure out what the replier means by this. I have tried their example in my custom loop which looks identical to the OP, how ever the pagination does not work. It does not show up.

I also have this issue in this loop:

```
$attr = array(
    'align' => 'left',
    'class' => 'thumbnail imageRight',
    'width' => 350,
    'height' => 350
);

if(have_posts()){
    while(have_posts()){
        the_post();
        ?>
        <div class="post">
            <?php the_post_thumbnail('medium', $attr); ?>
            <h1><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h1>
            <p><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p>
        </div>
        <?php
    }

    next_posts_link('&laquo; Older Entries');
    previous_posts_link('Newer Entries &raquo;');
}
```

Where the pagination will not show up at all, If I echo something above and below I see the echoed text, obv, but I do not see the  pagination links....

I have set WP to display 3 posts per page, and I have over 45 posts in the database.

Comment: See: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/77661/next-posts-link-works-only-with-original-wp-query/77666#77666

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue over and over - i dont know if you are using a custom page template, but in the end i just used an archive page instead of querying a category or post type - for example archive-portfolio.php and the pagination just worked on that. - some of these problems cause hours of irritation, but this seemed to fix it.